# create a constructor that by default builds a class array

Tags: java

I was required to create a constructor that by default builds a class array of
10 auto-initialized 0's
Assuming that the A is a class for a single int array
How can I create this constructor? I am complete Java beginner, so forgive me if the question is stupid
Thank.

Comment: Well, do you know how to declare a constructor? And do you know how to initialize an instance variable within a constructor? And do you know how to create an array? It's hard to help when we don't know exactly what you're stuck on.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int a[] = new int[10];
    // check that we have 10 elements and all of them = 0
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
```